# Reset state of link after clicking

Tags: html, css

I have a button like so:

[image]

When I hover over it, it looks like this:

[image]

When I click on it, it'll take me to a new tab that shows my resume. However, when I come back, there's an underline that I'd like to remove:

[image]

And I can and did remove it because I styled the `:focus` part of the button:

```
.resume-button:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

The problem arises when the user tries to hover over the link again. It's not hovering anymore because the link is still "clicked"; hence when I hover, the color of the text "Resume" remains white and won't change color until I click somewhere else to reset the link. How can I reset the state of the `<a>` without clicking on some other part of the website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try active and visited state to cover all possibilities. Sometimes link stays active after using browser back button, and links may be marked as visited during normal web browsing.

```
a:active, a:visited {
color: #fff;
}
```

Link can have four states:

1. a:link  - a normal, unvisited link
2. a:visited - a link the user has visited
3. a:hover - a link when the user mouses over it
4. a:active - link in the moment when clicked

These are the pseudoclasses and they should be declared in this specified order, because in a timeline they can happen only one after other.

People tend to think some shortcuts helpful in remembering the right sequence for example: LoVeHAte.

Comment: When I hover again, the color of the text is displaying properly. But when I'm not hovering, the default blue color of the link is shown instead. How can I change that to display white? I tried to add `color: #FFF` to `:focus` but that isn't working.

Comment: Please don't fight guys :) thank you for the link states. It was helpful and the order definitely mattered.

Answer (score 2):

Use `:active` selector instead. `:focus` is selected thing, `:active`  is pressed thing.

Answer (score 2):

the one you're looking for is `:visited`

```
a:visited{ /*styles */}
```

Use the `:link` selector to style links to unvisited pages, 
the `:hover` selector to style links when you mouse over them, 
and the `:active` selector to style links when you click on them.